# Update table in specific rows based on conditions for multiple previous rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

My dataset consists of daily (actually business days, but it shouldn't matter for the answer) timeseries for different companies and I work with PostgreSQL. I have an indicator variable in my dataset taking values 1, -1 and most of the times 0. For better readability of the question I refer to days where the indicator variable is unequal to zero as indicator days.

So for all indicator days that are preceded by another indicator day for the same company in the previous three days, the indicator variable shall be updated to zero.

We can work with the following example dataset:

```
day            company   indicator
2012-01-04     A         0
2012-01-04     B         0
2012-01-05     A         0
2012-01-05     B         -1
2012-01-06     A         0
2012-01-06     B         0
2012-01-09     A         0
2012-01-09     B         0
2012-01-10     A         0
2012-01-10     B         1
2012-01-11     A         1
2012-01-11     B         1
2012-01-12     A         0
2012-01-12     B         0
2012-01-13     A         1
2012-01-13     B         1
```

So the indicator values that have to be updated to zero are: on 2012-01-10 the entry for company B, on 2012-01-11 the entry for company B and on 2012-01-13 both entries, because all these are preceded by another indicator day for the same company within 3 business days.

I tried the following

```
    UPDATE test SET indicator = 0 
    WHERE day IN (
    SELECT day
      FROM (
           SELECT company, day, 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN indicator <> 0 THEN 1 END) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day 
                    ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As cnt
           FROM test
           ) alias
      WHERE cnt >= 2)
```

The idea was to count the days where the indicator variable is unequal to zero for the current day and the 3 preceding days. If it counts more than 1, it updates the indicator value to zero. Unfortunately it is not able to distinguish between companies. So what it does in the example data, is on 2012-01-11 it updates also the entry for company A to zero, because on the day before there is an indicator day for B.

Maybe I would need someting like  "partition by company" for the update, but it doesn't exist.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it, or how to solve my problem with another approach?

Comment: The problem seems the way you are using to find the previous 3 rows. That's removing the possibility of filtering by company. Cannot you just make a subquery: "select top 3 where subquery_day < query_day and subquery_company = query_company order by desc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql allows you to use more than one column for the IN statement, so I think you can just change your query to:

```
UPDATE test SET indicator = 0 
WHERE (day, company) IN (
SELECT day, company
    FROM (
        SELECT company, day, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN indicator <> 0 THEN 1 END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY day 
                ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As cnt
        FROM test
        ) alias
    WHERE cnt >= 2)
```

To get the results you need.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb1a6/4)**

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know about that. That you very much @GarethD